# syntax error: '->' and syntax error: missing ';' before '->'

Tags: c++-cli

What's wrong with this syntax? I've tried for like 30 minutes different ways. Intellisense doesn't underline anything but it won't compile. Please let me know if you need more info and thank you in advance.

```
WSHttpBinding^ binding = gcnew WSHttpBinding();
TimeSpan^ t = gcnew TimeSpan->MaxValue;
binding->ReceiveTimeout = *t;
```

Comment: This isn't C++.

Comment: Two completely different languages.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ya, that's why they have different names with c++ being part of both.

Comment: @m4gik: I'm not sure if you've misunderstood Neil's point, or are just being a jerk for no reason. You tagged your question as [c++] rather than [c++-cli], and nothing in your question indicated that you realized you didn't have C++ code. There are no clairvoyants here; you need to tag your questions correctly if you want attention from people who will understand them.

Comment: @ruakh I've been sassing Neil because instead of correcting the issue he decided to provide an unnecessary, disrespectful comment. Everytime I use this site people feel the need to make others feel small and are seemingly ignorant of the fact that people don't know everything (why they are here in the first place). There's no point to any of these comments and I obviously would've tagged it appropriately had I known that it was wrong. People here seem to often mistake not knowing something for laziness when the whole point is for people to come here because they don't know something lol.

Comment: @m4gik: Re: "instead of correcting the issue he decided to provide an unnecessary, disrespectful comment": Nonsense. Chain of events: (1) you post a question mistagged as C++. (2) Neil points out that it's not C++. (3) You identify the correct language in a comment, and add "Duh", as if everyone should have known what you meant. (You later delete this comment.) You don't fix your tags. (4) **He fixes your tags for you**, with an explanatory comment. (5) You continue "sassing Neil", **pretending that you already knew** what you now admit you didn't know!

Comment: @ruakh The comment was unnecessary, disrespectful, and 10x the amount of effort has been spent on an incorrect tag that I didn't know was incorrect than actually spent on getting to the answer... That is the nonsense!! What value does the comment "This isn't C++" add after he corrected the tag? The answer is none. It's just someone enjoying talking down to someone. Simply fixing the tag is the only necessary, helpful part of what he said.

Comment: @m4gik: Re: "What value does the comment 'This isn't C++" add after he corrected the tag? The answer is none": Well then, it's a good thing that that didn't happen. The "This isn't C++" comment is *before* you told him that your code was actually C++/CLI; he corrected your tag *after* you told him that. Please stop lying; it's pointless and juvenile.

Comment: @ruakh You are incorrect as when I came back to the question the first time to see if there were any answers I was greeted with the tag changed appropriately and also the unnecessary comment. Maybe he commented then changed the tag?

Comment: @m4gik: Mea culpa, I must have misread the timestamps. I apologize. (I still think your comments were unnecessarily jerky, but at least now I understand where you're coming from.)

Comment: @ruakh Thank you for apologizing and I admit my comments were unnecessarily jerky. I was upset that again I came to this site for help with good intentions and was chastised.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
WSHttpBinding^ binding = gcnew WSHttpBinding();
binding->ReceiveTimeout = System::TimeSpan::MaxValue;
```